# How to turn an integer into a list and then add the list together

Tags: python, python-3.x

So if user enters e.g. `12345678` I want to change it into a list so I can add all 8 numbers together and then divide by 10. How can I do that? I used `Numgiven` as the variable for user input.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I suggest that you take the tour and familiarize yourself with how this site works. Specifically, the site is not meant to literally solve homework (I suggest a minute of googling).

Comment: However, I will give you some tips: 1) The user input is not an integer (yet) and 2) Look at iterating over a list. By combining both those points you should easily be able to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the integer to a string and use `map(int, string)` or a list comprehension:

```
>>> Numgiven = 12345678 
>>> sum(map(int, str(Numgiven)))
36
>>> sum([int(x) for x in str(Numgiven)])
36
```

Comment: The thing is I ask the user for the input so he/she can input any random 7 or 8 digit number. e.g.23487327

Comment: The thing is, that also works for user input. If you do not know how to get an user input, please read the python manual, especially about `input` build-in function.

Comment: @sadsadsad How does that affect this answer? You honestly should take a step back and try to learn the basics yourself if you don't see how this fits your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Since a string is a sequence, it is very easy:

```
usr = input("Gis a number: ")
total = sum([int(i) for i in usr])
final_value = total/10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 123456789
num_str = str(num)
sum = 0
for digit in num_str:
     sum = int(digit) + sum
print (sum)
result = sum/10
```

Comment: the OP tagged python3.x, so would it not be better if you wrote the code in python 3.x way?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @vaultah ... this code snippet is not verbose...what additional info has to be added for such answers ....so that future aspect is taken care of..?

Comment: @Juna In general, describe (conceptually) what a snippet does and why one would use your concept (e.g., state that your answer does not use 'difficult' concepts such as a list comprehension, making it useful to beginners).

Comment: @bas jansen ...  Surely will add these details in my answers from now-onwards. Thanks for good suggestions.

Comment: @Juna OP is handling user input, not variable .